# Access to MySQL after closing connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem with access to my datebase MySQL after closing it. I use Windows Form and MySql Connector from MySql official website to connect to datebase. I use MySQL in XAMPP.

If I open my connection I can do a simple query. **But when I close a connection I can still do this query**. Why?

Here is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim polaczenieMySql As New MySqlConnection
    Dim mySQL As PolaczenieMySQL

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        mySQL = New PolaczenieMySQL(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPolaczMySQL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPolaczMySQL.Click
        mySQL.Polacz()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RozlaczMySQL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRozlaczMySQL.Click
        mySQL.Rozlacz()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnZapytanie_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnZapytanieMySQL.Click
        Dim zapytanie As String = "SELECT title, price, book_id from books"
        mySQL.WykonajZapytanie(zapytanie)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And my connection class:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class PolaczenieMySQL
    Dim polaczenie As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()
    Dim glowneOkno As Form1

    Public Sub New(form As Form1)
        glowneOkno = form
    End Sub

    Public Sub Polacz()
        polaczenie.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=test")

        Try
            polaczenie.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Połączono z bazą danych MySQL.")
            glowneOkno.labelPolaczenieMySQL.Text = "Połączono"
            glowneOkno.labelPolaczenieMySQL.ForeColor = Color.Green
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Nie udało się połączyć z bazą danych MySQL: " & myerror.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Rozlacz()
        Try
            polaczenie.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Rozłączono z bazy danych MySQL.")
            glowneOkno.labelPolaczenieMySQL.Text = "Nie połączono"
            glowneOkno.labelPolaczenieMySQL.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Błąd rozłączenia z bazy danych MySQL: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            polaczenie.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub WykonajZapytanie(ByVal zapytanie As String)
        Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
        Dim bSource As New BindingSource

        Try
            Dim komenda As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(zapytanie, polaczenie)
            SDA.SelectCommand = komenda
            SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
            bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
            glowneOkno.DataGridViewMySQL.DataSource = bSource
            SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Nie jesteś połączony z bazą")
        End Try   
    End Sub

End Class
```

As I said before, after closing connection (`mySQL.Rozlacz()`) I can still do a query (`mySQL.WykonajZapytanie(zapytanie)`). What is wrong with this?

PS. Sorry for my polish names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the docs about the [DbDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d(v=vs.110).aspx) you could read this remark

> The Fill method retrieves the data from the data source using a SELECT
>   statement. The IDbConnection object associated with the select command
>   must be valid, but it does not need to be open. If the IDbConnection
>   is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data and
>   then closed. If the connection is open before Fill is called, it
>   remains open.

The MySqlDataAdapter inherits from the DbDataAdapter and there is no override of the Fill method, so it is the inherited class (DbDataAdapter) that works with the associated command, reopening the closed connection and then closing it.

**EDIT** 
You asked also how to avoid this behavior, well you could add a boolean property to your class `PolaczenieMySQL` that maintains the state of your MySqlConnection

```
Private _isDead As Boolean

Public Property IsDead() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _isDead
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As String)
        _isDead = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Now you could set this property to False when you open the connection and True when you close it.
Then check its value before executing the `WykonajZapytanie` sub

```
Public Sub WykonajZapytanie(ByVal zapytanie As String)

    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource

    if Me.IsDead Then
        Throw new Exception("Invalid usage of this class")
    End If
    ......
End Sub
```

Notice that there is a simpler check using the MySqlConnection property `State`

```
if polaczenie.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
    ......
```

but, given the fact that in your `Rozlacz` method you dispose the connection I suggest to implement the first workaround.

Finally, I really think that you should change the whole pattern of usage. The connection should be opened, used and closed in the same method where it is required. Your actual infrastructure render this impossible. It is better to get rid of the `Polacz` and `Rozlacz` and use the mentioned pattern without the need of a global variable for the connection.

Comment: Oh, so it works like that. Now I understand why I still have an access. So how can I avoid this situation? What should I use instead of Fill method?